# how to notify client of stale content?

Tags: angular, azure-devops

**How do we notify the user of the web app that the content is stale?**

We have an angular app that is released with Azure DevOps. The users of the web app will sometimes leave their browser window open for days, weeks, and sometimes months. They'll be looking at a form that may have gone through 3 iterations, and they'll start doing data entry.

**Is it possible to notify the user that the content is old?**

Comment: It's pretty easy to notify the user that x minutes has passed since their last keystroke or request or whatever with an `Observable.timer`.

Comment: Yeah I'd feel guilty going after this instead of just pointing you towards a quick google of like "angular idle activity timer" where there's already loads of example options from basic to more complex.

Comment: Nobody will be awarded, so no more activities on your bounties.

Answer (score 2):

In order to notify clients for a stale content you have to know how to determine that content is stale first.

You can do it based on time. Save the current time when the app loads then check periodically if the delta between the current time and the time the app was loaded is < to a given threshold. This is in my opinion **not** the best idea.

A better idea in my opinion would be to save an app version in your app. If you bundle your frontend into a tiny backend project to serve it then the backend could expose the frontend version on a given endpoint. If you only have a backend that serves the assets (static), you can still do something similar by generating a JSON file with the content `{ "version": "x.y.z"}` that you can query on the frontend that static JSON file and compare it with the current one. You can then apply some logic like if there's only been a patch version bump, we don't notify the user but if there's been a minor change or a breaking change then we pop a warning to the user (up to you really for that logic).

In order to do that, you need to think about the following:

- How to have a version number that makes sense?
- How to pass it to the app?
- How do we poll that data and detect an update?
- How do we make that visible to the user?

Let's try to go through them 1 by 1.

## How to have a version number that makes sense?

I think that the best thing you could come up with would be some automated way on CI to create releases based on your commit names (using [semver](https://semver.org/)). I do not know which CI you're using (if any) so I'm going to give a few examples and hopefully you can find what suits you. At work we use Gitlab and Gitlab CI. We've setup `semantic-release` which you can find here: https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release this project has some pre-configured setups like the [Github](https://github.com/semantic-release/github) and the [Gitlab](https://github.com/semantic-release/gitlab) ones for example. But you should be able to set it up anywhere really.

This will create git releases for you. If you do not want to set this up and do some manual versioning, it'll be as easy as writing a JSON file, for example `version.json` and edit the content `{ "version": "x.y.z"}`.

## How to pass it to the app?

Assuming you've decided to create a `version.json` file, simply put it in the `assets` folder of your project. It'll be served like every other assets.

If you've decided to setup your CI with automated releases, you can find the latest git tag within a script and generate the `version.json` file.

## How do we poll that data and detect an update?

Create a service with a code around those lines:

```
export class UpdateService {
  private static UPDATE_VERSION_INTERVAL_MS = 10_000;

  public versionAtLoadTime$: Observable<string> = this.getRemoteVersion().pipe(
    shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false })
  );

  public isNewVersionAvailable$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest(
    this.versionAtLoadTime$,
    timer(UpdateService.UPDATE_VERSION_INTERVAL_MS).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.getRemoteVersion())
    )
  ).pipe(
    filter(([localVersion, remoteVersion]) => localVersion !== remoteVersion),
    mapTo(true),
    shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false })
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // make sure we try to load it asap
    // it's not something we want to get rid of
    // so no need to clean up the subscription here
    this.versionAtLoadTime$.subscribe();
  }

  public getRemoteVersion(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>('https://your-app.com/assets/version.json');
  }
}
```

## How do we make that visible to the user?

If you want to display the current version (which I usually like to put somewhere with a tiny font-size), use: `versionAtLoadTime$`. That's just bonus.

In your form, to display a message when there's a new version:

```
<div *ngIf="isNewVersionAvailable$ | async">
  Warning! There's a new version available. You should reload the page as soon as possible to get it
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of Angular and I don't know whether you expect a piece of code as an answer. Also I probably view this question from too high a level. On the other hand, the question leaves out the details. So answering the big picture might be valid.

*Is it possible to notify the user that the content is old?*

Yes.

*How do we notify the user of the web app that the content is stale?*

Have a look at "hot" questions on SO. Keep a couple of questions open for some minutes. At some time you'll notice that a message appears that indicates that an edit has been made or a comment has been added. This is an example:

[image: edit notice]

This functionality is realized using Web Sockets.

[Code on the web page](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js) opens a connection to `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` and subscribes to updates of a question. That is, it simply sends the number of the question (and other information), e.g., `1-question-68733421`, to the server.

The server registers the subscription. From then on, if the server detects that the page content is stale, for example, because the subscribed to question has been edited, the server replies with structured data (i.e. JSON data) to notify the subscriber:

```
 {
    "data": {
        "a": "post-edit",
        "id": 68733421,
        "acctid": 3433601
    }
}
```

Code on the web page parses this data and can infer, what content has changed and notifies the user with an appropriate message, e.g., by presenting a banner to this effect.

I think that for this problem the [Publisher-Subscriber pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/publisher-subscriber) could be applied.

Please comment whether this helps.

Comment: I initially thought about something like this being the answer also.  That being said, how long are the sockets or subscriptions kept open?  I would assume that at some point before "months" it will stop trying to send updates?

Comment: @Matt one solution would be: the web page sends "pings" to the server and if the server does not respond in a timely manner, the web page closes and reopens the connection to the server. If this

Answer (score 1):

what we do in our company to keep the data updated is that we monitor **signalR** connection. if the connection is lost we show a proper alert that you are disconnected and data is not reliable anymore. when it reconnects we clear the grid and call an Api with all new data while we also listen to new push data and merge incoming Api's array of data with single push notifications. so if the user is away everything remains updated by signal but if the user lost the live connection by any cause like disconnecting or sleep or hibernate or ... we refresh the data through the Api. simple answer but I wish it helps.